# OFFSET function ignore blank cell in range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to SUM last 3 values in range they ignore it blank cell in a range.

My formula is:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((A:A<>0),0),0)),LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))-3,0,3))
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `SUM(A5:A9)`? Your question lacks all of your constraints. You may want to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use something like AGGREGATE or LARGE(IF()):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))/($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))<>""),{1,2,3})))))
```

[image]

Comment: if I want to change the number of values I should change {1,2,3} to {1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ...}

Comment: @SmekeriBezPrezimena yes.